# Is there an option in ubuntu to connect to a network even if it's not broadcasting its SSID?

Tags: wireless, windows-7

In windows there is an option under network connections
"connect even if the network is not broadcasting":

[image]

Is there a similar option in Ubuntu? I'm asking this because I live in an appartment with lots of wifi and often my pc cannot find my own SSID. Probably it will be solved if i can make it to forcefully connect even if it's not broadcasting its SSID. I cannot find anything under 'edit connections' for that matter.

thanks

Comment: Create a connection manually, and put the hidden SSID (name of the network) into the SSID field; you can then auto connect to the network even if it's not broadcasting (comment and not question due to not be in able to put steps here for this)

Answer (score 1):

To connect to a hidden wireless network:
1. Click on NetworkManager in the top panel.
2. Select Connect to a hidden wireless network. Ubuntu will then open
the “Connect to Hidden Wireless Network” window.
3. In the Network name field, enter the name of the network. This is also
known as the ssid (Service Set Identifier). You must enter the name exactly
how it was given to you. For example, if the name is “UbuntuWireless,”
entering “ubuntu-wireless” will not work as the “U” and “W”
are both uppercase in the correct name.
4. In the Wireless security field, select one of the options. If the network
is an open network, leave the field set to “None.” If you do not know the
correct setting for the field, you will not be able to connect to the hidden
network.
5. Click the Connect button. If the network is secure, you will be prompted
for the password. Provided you have entered all of the details correctly,
the network should then connect, and you will receive an on-screen
notification informing you that the connection was a success.
As is the case with visible wireless networks, hidden wireless network
settings will be saved once a connection is made, and the wireless network
will then appear in the list of saved connections.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. I tried your suggestion and think it succeeded, however I had to try a couple of times before it connected to my wifi (asked 2-3 times for my pasword which was correctly spelled just like the name of my SSID). I will see if my problem repeats or not.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately your suggestion does not work. Yesterday I encountered again that my wifi network was not found, even if it was set up as an hidden network.